# Amazon S3 uploading twice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-s3

I have a weird problem with uploading image to an Amazon S3 bucket.

What I observed is that when I upload to my bucket after I haven't use the app for a while (an hour?), the progress runs from 0 to 100% TWICE before the upload is completed. For example, I have a the following code block to determine how much % has been uploaded:

```
// Track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {[weak self](bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) in
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

    let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)

    print(" totalBytesSent \(totalBytesSent) / totalBytesExpectedToSend \(totalBytesExpectedToSend) progress = \(progress * 100 ) %")

    circularProgressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)

        })
}
```

And for the printout, I see the following printout twice and I observe my progress circle to do two 360 degrees rotation within a 5 second period (upload time).

```
 totalBytesSent 32677 / totalBytesExpectedToSend 107360 progress = 30.4368 %
 totalBytesSent 65354 / totalBytesExpectedToSend 107360 progress = 60.8737 %
 totalBytesSent 98031 / totalBytesExpectedToSend 107360 progress = 91.3105 %
 totalBytesSent 107360 / totalBytesExpectedToSend 107360 progress = 100.0 %
 totalBytesSent 107360 / totalBytesExpectedToSend 107360 progress = 100.0 %
```

And the weird thing is that if I re-upload anything afterwards, it works as expected the print out going to 100% only once.

Below is how I deal with S3:

```
// 1. Save file to disk and retreive NSURL before we can store to Amazon S3
let path: String = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("\(CURRENT_USER_UID)).jpg")
let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.1)!
imageData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
let url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

// 2. Create upload request
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.bucket = "myBucket"
uploadRequest.key = "\(CURRENT_USER_UID)\(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)).jpg"
uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.PublicRead
uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpg"
uploadRequest.body = url

// Track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {[weak self](bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) in
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)

        print(" totalBytesSent \(totalBytesSent) / totalBytesExpectedToSend \(totalBytesExpectedToSend) progress = \(progress * 100 ) %")

        circularProgressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)

    })
}

// 3. Upload to Amazon S3
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in

    if let error = task.error {
        if error.domain == AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain {

            MRProgressOverlayView.dismissOverlayForView(self.view, animated: true)
            self.enableUserInteraction()

            switch task.error?.code {
            case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Cancelled.rawValue?:
                break
            case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Paused.rawValue?:
                break
            default:
                self.showErrorAlert("Error uploading image #1", message: "\(error)")
            }
        } else {
            self.showErrorAlert("Error uploading image #2", message: "\(error)")
            MRProgressOverlayView.dismissOverlayForView(self.view, animated: true)
            self.enableUserInteraction()
        }
    } else {
        if task.completed {
            let imgLink = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/\(uploadRequest.key!)"
            self.postToFirebase(imgLink, userCoordinate: userCoordinate)

        } else {
            self.showErrorAlert("Error uploading image #3", message: "Please try again later")
            MRProgressOverlayView.dismissOverlayForView(self.view, animated: true)
            self.enableUserInteraction()
        }
    }
    return nil
```

----UPDATE------
After looking at the console, I observe that the first upload was not successful because the following error

2016-08-20 16:42:51.524 Letzzee[20327:176849] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.5 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:211 | -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

However, I dont get why this occurs periodically. And I dont think it is anything to do with my internet connection because

1. I have tried on both my phone with WIFI/3G and simulator with WIFI. I dont. If it is internet issue, it should happen all the time or not so periodically.
2. The upload ALWAYS goes to 100% and the it shows that message. Then it AUTOMATICALLY re-upload and the 2nd time is almost always successful.